# coloring cell while exporting dataframe to excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I have dataframe "df" as below:

```
x = [1,3,5,7] 
y1 = [3,2,2,2] 
y2 = [2,5,2,2] 
y3 = [7,2,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y1': y1, 'y2': y2, 'y3': y3})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I want the excel output file shows the same color in mutual values of column x with other columns. [image]:

Answer (score 5):

You can use [styles](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel) if colors are specify by `dictionary`:

```
def color(a):
    d = {1:'yellow', 3:'green', 5:'blue', 7:'red'}

    d1 = {k: 'background-color:' + v for k, v in d.items()}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=a.index, columns=a.columns)
    df1 = a.applymap(d1.get).fillna('')
    return df1

df.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives this error: "AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Comment: @P.J What is your pandas version?